# Thermodynamic pressure in liquids

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

In equilibrium and from the theory of classical thermodynamics, we must have that the pressure in a system is constant throughout. Consider a system like liquid in a test tube. We know from fluid mechanics (statics) that the pressure at the bottom is higher than the pressure at the top. How do we reconcile these two pictures? Do real liquids "need" more thermodynamic variables to describe them than the simple $(U,V,N)$ picture often used and, if so, does including these other macroscopic variables invalidate that "in equilibrium ...we must have that the pressure in a system is constant throughout"?